# Why my JSON string is null?

Tags: php, null, json

I have written a code in PHP , to see the JSON string output. But i am getting null value.

```
<?php

 $l=array();

 $l[] = array('a'=>'@cÐaÐjÔÐ J kf _ÞÒi^ ','b'=>']éÞ[Ñ¯Ð QtÍ]hà_ , `ËSÐ J heZ Òhi');

 echo $j = json_encode($l);

?>
```

**Output-:**

```
  [{"a":null,"b":null}]
```

Why the JSON output is coming in null. I am expecting that there must be character encoding problem.

i want the output in following format.

```
[{"a":"@cÐaÐjÔÐ J kf _ÞÒi^","b":"]éÞ[Ñ¯Ð QtÍ]hà_ , `ËSÐ J heZ Òhi"}]
```

Please help me out. Please suggest me some solution

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use [utf8_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) the string before pushing to array and then json_encode since [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/json_encode) works only only with utf8 encoded data

```
$l=array();

$l[] = array('a'=>utf8_encode('@cÐaÐjÔÐ J kf _ÞÒi^ '),
'b'=>utf8_encode(']éÞ[Ñ¯Ð QtÍ]hà_ , `ËSÐ J heZ Òhi'));

echo json_encode($l);
```

Ok looks like your issue is not so simple,and you need to use

```
htmlentities( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE);
```

to handle the situation

```
$array = array("a"=>htmlentities( (string) "@cÐaÐjÔÐ J kf _ÞÒi^ ", ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE),
               "b"=>htmlentities( (string) "]éÞ[Ñ¯Ð QtÍ]hà_ , `ËSÐ J heZ Òhi", ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE)
              
             );

$json = json_encode($array);
echo ($json);
```

check here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mh8-7ua

You need to add as above in your array elements.

Comment: Yes i got this output . [{"a":"@c\u00c3\u0090a\u00c3\u0090j\u00c3\u0094\u00c3\u0090 J kf _\u00c3\u009e\u00c3\u0092i^ ","b":"]\u00c3\u00a9\u00c3\u009e[\u00c3\u0091\u00c2\u00af\u00c3\u0090 Qt\u00c3\u008d]h\u00c3\u00a0_ , `\u00c3\u008bS\u00c3\u0090 J heZ \u00c3\u0092hi"}]  , so how to replace this \u00 to real string....

Comment: Make sure your header header is set to UTF8, you can add <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> on the HTML header.

Comment: Yes i have used <meta charset='utf-8'/> but still i am getting this result.

Comment: If you just echo '@cÐaÐjÔÐ J kf _ÞÒi^ ' ;  what u see ?

Comment: I am getting the ouput -: @cÐaÐjÔÐ J kf _ÞÒi^   , here there is no problem. but the JSON output not coming properly.

Comment: No i am getting this error -: 
Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\Calendar\Calendar Work\newjson.php on line 10
[null]

Comment: Thank you man , yes i checked it , it works really fine thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your described behaviour using a limited encoding.

Check the file encoding of your php script. Make sure that it is set to unicode or utf8 if it is available.

Otherwise you'll have to convert your string to utf8 first like Abhik posted in his answer.

Your output will then look like

```
[{"a":"@c\u00d0a\u00d0j\u00d4\u00d0 J kf _\u00de\u00d2i^ ",
  "b":"]\u00e9\u00de[\u00d1\u00af\u00d0 Qt\u00cd]h\u00e0_ , `\u00cbS\u00d0 J heZ \u00d2hi"}]
```

[That is working as intended, since](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)...

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
>   represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
>   by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
>   encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A though
>   F can be upper or lowercase.  So, for example, a string containing
>   only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
>   "\u005C".

Comment: Yes i changed to Unicode but i got the output in following ways. [{"a":"@c\u00d0a\u00d0j\u00d4\u00d0 J kf _\u00de\u00d2i^ ","b":"]\u00e9\u00de[\u00d1\u00af\u00d0 Qt\u00cd]h\u00e0_ , `\u00cbS\u00d0 J heZ \u00d2hi"}]

Comment: Thats ok, since your json recipient will convert it back to output it properly (usually in a browser).