# Language support in creating json from php

Tags: php, json

I would like to json in Korean. The language of my aap is English. The problem is that its replace Korean language to `?????`. My code snippet is:

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli ( '50.62.209.85:3306', 'local', 'root123', 'android');
// Check if album id is posted as GET parameter
 $myq = $mysqli ->query ( 'SELECT id, url, name FROM HollywoodMovies' );
 while ( $myr = $myq->fetch_assoc () ) {
 $array["items"][] = (array(
'id' => $myr['id'],
'id' => $myr['url'],
'title' => $myr['name'],
));
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645243/why-my-json-string-is-null/21645380#21645380 might help you..

Comment: Are you sure the data is coming correctly from the database...?!

Comment: Tried utf8_encode or something like https://gist.github.com/muhqu/863757? What do the results look like?

Comment: You should remove your MySQL connection credentials.

Comment: why you put comma `,` at the end of title index in array (or is this typo mistake) and two index with same name `id`??

Comment: @BluAngel its work fine only problem in title its just allow english but korean language replace with ????? question mark

Comment: can you try that line `print_r($array)` before `echo json_encode($array);` and see what is output print?

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode documentation](http://ch2.php.net/json_encode)

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )
```

For paramater value:

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded

Check if your data is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: okay thanks but in above code what can i do because i dont know php please help me.

Comment: Okay,  but for graphicly manage your database? Creat, edit, view table,  etc.

Comment: So what is the collation of the columns who content text data for the table HollywoodMovies ?
You can see that with the following navigation:
server -> db -> table -> structure